# Node js not working on windows 2008 server

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run my application on Windows 2008 server and i am getting the same error  "This application is only supported on Windows 7,Windows Server 2008 R2, or higher".

Can someone suggest on how to fix this.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly share some information about your application so we can help to troubleshoot. Also, share with us what you have tried so far and what you have found. To start off,  which version of nodeJS are you using?

Comment: I have created an application in Node js which i want to run it on windows 2008 server. When i try to run that app on the server i am getting that error that i have mentioned. I have marked my app to run it on older version of node js still it doesnt help.

Comment: Have you checked which version of node is installed on the machine and which version your application is designed to work with?

Comment: node -v : 4.7.0, npm-v : 2.15.11 - I have installed this on the server and in package in updated that my app to run in that version only. "engines": { "node": "<=4.7.0", "npm":"<=2.15.11" }, "engineStrict": true

Answer (score 2):

Please try to install the Node 4.x LTS version. The current LTS version is 8.12.0.

You can check this link to get supported NodeJS version https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Take note that ES6 will not work in there.

Comment: I am able to install Node4.x on server. I have written my application in node and created an app for that.I want to run it on 2008 server with it is still throwing the error that it is not supported there. In pacakge.json i have marked it to run on node4.x or lower versions but still its not helping. any inputs on how i can resolve it ?   "engines": {
    "node": "<=4.7.0",
    "npm":"<=2.15.11"
  },
  "engineStrict": true

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I followed the link https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/
and installed Version 8x.

So far works well. If some have a higher version which is works, please share.

Comment: This worked for me on Amazon AWS Windows Server 2008 R2 DataCenter Service Pack 1, 64 bit.

Comment: @ToddKrueger which version of nodejs do you have installed?

Comment: Worked for me on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.